# How to retrieve a DataFrame from a ResultProxy object which contains CSV data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I have a DataFrame object that I am firstly converting into a CSV as such:

```
valsCSV = vals.to_csv() #where vals is a dataframe with a single row
```

and then I am inserting this valsCSV into the 'userdata' column of a table using SQLAlchemy as follows:

```
sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO "+ tablename + "(username, userdata) VALUES ('"+testName+"', '"+ valsCSV +"')"
connection.execute(sqlStatement)
```

Then, to retrieve the data, I execute a query that returns a ResultProxy object as follows:

```
sqlStatement = "SELECT userdata FROM " + tablename + " WHERE username='" + username +"';"
rs = dbConnection.execute(sqlStatement) #where rs will be a ResultProxy object
```

The aim is to reverse this process after retrieving the ResultProxyObject and attain the initial DataFrame.

Remark: the reason why I have a one-row Dataframe, in the beginning, is solution-specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get the CSV string out of your query, you can use `io.StringIO` to get `pd.read_csv` to convert it back into a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})
res = df.to_csv(None, index=False)

df2 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(res))
print(df2)
```

Yields:

```
   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
```

Comment: Although I figured out a different solution that worked for my scenario, I will upvote this because this is a viable solution to the question. I did try this approach at first but I couldn't seem to make it work without having indexed into the row entry as follows:
retrievedString = rs[i][0] #where i is the row index
Then I continued with read_csv(StringIO(res)) as suggested (I found a similar solution for another question that I can't find now). In case you are the person who suggested that solution, I'm upvoting. If you think this is a potential duplicate, let me know and I'll delete this.